# In The Matrix Resurrections, why was Morpheus needed to find Neo?

Tags: the-matrix

I believe it was Bugs who said that Morpheus needed to be freed in order to find Neo, and Neo was actually the one who helped them find Morpheus. Why was Morpheus needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Resurrections*, in the beginning, Neo subconsciously has a desire to escape the Matrix, as he always has. Consciously, he wants to believe this Matrix is the real world. His job is a game developer, similar to the first movie (where he's a hacker/programmer), and his creative output has led to the wildly successful Matrix game trilogy. He feels like something is wrong with the world, and thinks he may be going crazy. The Analyst keeps prescribing Blue Pills to him to help suppress those memories.

He's working on the fourth game, and his memories, which have been insufficiently Blue Pilled by the Analyst to try and keep him under control, leak out in the form of creative expression. This leads him to create a Modal, which is a virtual reality simulation of the Matrix inside the Matrix. The characters he creates are influenced by his subconscious recollections of his previous memories.

The "video game" character of Morpheus is a representation of Neo's subconscious desire to escape the Matrix he now finds himself in. Morpheus has to escape the Modal so that he can try to convince Neo's conscious self that he's in a simulation and needs to escape. It's basically Neo's subconscious trying to send the conscious Neo a message about his predicament.

Morpheus was needed in order to convince his conscious self that he really was in the Matrix and needs to escape. Without this push, he might have continued to Blue Pill himself indefinitely, which is what the Analyst wanted. Total control over the anomaly that kept the Matrix's code stable, similar to the Architect's design to keep the Matrix stable by turning it off and on again every few years/decades.